# Best API model design

Tags: java, android

I have offline JSON definitions (in assets folder) - and with them I create my data model. It has like 8 classes which all inherit (extend) one abstract Model class.

Would it be better solution if I parse the JSON and keep the model in memory (more or less everything is Integer or String) through the whole life cycle of the App or would it be smarter if I parse the JSON files as they are needed?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing the files and storing all the data in the memory will definitely give you a speed advantage. The problem with this solution is that if your application will go to back-ground (the user receives a phone call or just leaves the app by his will), no one can guarantee that the data will stay intact in memory.

This data can be clear by the GC if the system decided that it needs more memory.

This means that when the user comes back to the application and if you relay on the fact that the data is in the memory you might face an exception. So you need to consider this situation.

And from that point of you it is good to store you data on a file that can be parsed at a desired time, even thought this might be a slower solution.

Another solution you may look at is to parse this data at first application start-up to an SQLite DB and use it from there, or even store it in the DB in the first place. This will give you the advantages of both worlds, you would not have to parse the data before using it, and you will have a quick access to it using a `Cursor` and you are not facing the problem of data deletion in case of insufficient memory in the system.

Comment: would a DB operation be cheaper than the previous ones mentioned? I.e. is retrieving a data from a table cheaper than parsing the JSON all over again and again for every request or is it cheaper than storing the model in the memory?

Comment: memory access would be the fastest, but getting your data from the DB will be much more cheaper then getting it from a file by parsing it. using DB you have an instant access to a specific desired row of data, while parsing the file would take more time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read all the file content at once and keep it as a static String somewhere in my application that is available to all application components (**SingleTone Pattern**) since usually Maintaining a small string in the memory is much cheaper than opening and closing files frequently.

To solve the **GC** point @Emil pointed out you can write your code something like this:

```
    public class DataManager {
    private static String myData;
    public static String getData(Context context){
        if(myData == null){
            loadData(context);
        }
        return myData;
    }
    private static void LoadData(Context context){
        context.getAssets().

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("data.txt"), "UTF-8")); 

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                String mLine = reader.readLine();
                builder.append(mLine);
            } while (mLine != null) 


            reader.close();
            myData = builder.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }   
 }
```

And from any class in your application that has a **valid Context** reference:

```
String data = DataManager.getData(context);
```